# How will the router forward packets destined for the following addresses

Tags: ip, router, forward, routetable

I have this IP forwarding work:

[image: IP forwarding work.]

Anyway, my idea was to get the range of the IP table and look up where the IPs belong to. But the first number does not belong anywhere (so I think). Kindly help. PS: I am not really looking for the final answer, just a dumbed down explanation for a newbie.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- a: Through gateway: 172.165.0.3
- b: Through gateway: 172.16.0.1
- c: Through gateway: 174.146.0.5
- d: Through gateway: 172.16.0.1
- e: Through gateway: 172.16.0.1

As you know the Subnetmask splits the IP-Address in host and network bits. 
For example:

a: IP: 203.235.17.5 is a member of the network 203.224.0.0/12, because it fits into the host range:
203.224.0.1 - 203.239.255.254

b,d,e go through the default gateway, because they don't fit into any of the other three routes. 
I hope this helps :-)